# Webpack SCSS Angular2

Tags: angular, sass, webpack

I am using the angularClass webpack starter kit. I love that I do not have to set the unit testing, what a relieve. Anyways in the `webpack.common.js` I added the following

```
loaders: [
        {
          test: /\.scss$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader'] // sass-loader not scss-loader
        }
      ],
```

under `module{}`, please note that the `loaders` array was not there.

I am getting an error saying

> parse failed - Error in path/to/scss/file - You may need an
>   appropriate loader to handle this file type

I can not figure out the reason for this. especially that I used webpack with ng1 and react and used the same loader.

The same issue happened with pug as well. I have of course followed every stack overflow and github issue but to no avail.

Comment: stoopid question : is `path/to/scss/file` really a `.scss` file ?

Comment: yes it is the correct path, when i replace the `.scss` with `.css` all works

Comment: it's working now?

Comment: No it is not, will take a longer look in the weekend. Its really annoying

Comment: No hope, if anyone has a solution do post please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution finally. OMFNG.

move all the objects in the array `rules` to `loaders`

That made the `scss` work, i think `pug` will work too like that will test and see. If it does not work will update this.